# java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

The error thrown or both:

```
    @Inject
    @Named("DummyString")
    lateinit var dummyString: String

    @Inject
    @Named("SomethingToRemember")
    lateinit var sthToRemember: String
```

but the following is fine:

```
    @Inject
    @Named("MySharedPrefs")
    lateinit var mySharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
```

Is there something special about provision and usage of String with Dagger?

**My Module**

```
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Named("MySharedPrefs")
    fun provideMySharedPrefs(context: Context) : SharedPreferences {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Named("DummyString")
    fun provideDummyString(): String {
        return "dummy dummy"
    }

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Named("SomethingToRemember")
    fun provideSthToRemember(@Named("MySharedPrefs") sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) : String {
        return sharedPreferences.getString("SomethingToRemember", "") ?: ""
    }
```

Error details:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface FormsPreviewAppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.myapp.android.MyApplication> {
                ^
      java.lang.String is injected at
          com.myapp.android.MyLinkActivity.sthToRemember
      com.myapp.android.MyActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.myapp.android.MyAppComponent → com.myapp.android.MyAppModule_Bindable_ContributesMyActivity.MyActivitySubcomponent]
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myapp:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

Comment: share the error !

Comment: Added, thanks @Anmol

Comment: Why are you injecting `String`? That's so wired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to use `@field:Named("DummyString")` instead of `@Named("DummyString")`
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/848